# Multipart in wso2 EI

Tags: wso2, multipartform-data, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a requirement where i am supposed to upload a gzip file to wso2 EI server.

I have a file(gzip) in a system(running java). I need to send this file to a API hosted in wso2ei, which will store this. Since file can be HUGE, I need the API to support multi part file upload. I want to write an API in wso2 EI which will support multipart and will take this file and store on some location on EI server itself.
I do not want to use VFS.

Below is the code that i tried but not working. Its creating a corrupted zip file. If i am giving a huge file , then i am getting out of memory error too. Though while using multipart, i was not expecting out of memory error(irrespective the size of file).

Note: I tried without decoding the body. With application/zip content type as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/upload" name="MultiPartAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" >
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="inputPayLoad" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <property expression="//mediate/data/text()" name="payload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="//mediate/data/@filename" name="fileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="===========" value="================="/>
                <property expression="$ctx:fileName" name="fileName"/>
            </log>
            <property expression="base64Decode(get-property('payload'))" name="DecodeBody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="File full path" expression="fn:concat('\home\files\gzip\',$ctx:fileName)" name="fileFullPath" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/octet-stream"/>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/octet-stream"/>
            <fileconnector.create>
                <source>{$ctx:fileFullPath}</source>
                <inputContent>{$ctx:DecodeBody}</inputContent>
            </fileconnector.create>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

BR//
Vipin Nirwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This give the details of above requirement.](https://medium.com/@zarulizham/wso2-ei-multipart-api-upload-attachment-342bd27419f5)